# How to Read Lucene.net returned query results

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I can't figure out how to read the results returned from a Lucene.net query.

I have this code:

**Initialization**

```
  var test = new Document();
            test.Add(new Field("id", "1", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            test.Add(new Field("title", "the title", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            test.Add(new Field("body", "the body of the question", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

            string path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "\\LuceneIndex";
            Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(path));
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);

            var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
            writer.AddDocument(test);

            writer.Optimize();
            writer.Flush(true, true, true);
            writer.Dispose();

            directory.Dispose();
            analyzer.Dispose();
```

**Reading the data**

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "ti", analyzer);

string path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "\\LuceneIndex";
Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(path));

IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);

Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("body", "body"));


TopDocs docs =  searcher.Search(query,5);
analyzer.Dispose();
searcher.Dispose();
```

I inspected the data in `docs`, but it doesn't contain the Id of the matched search results.

Comment: Your query string, `ti`, simply doesn't match anything in the index. Are you aware of the tokenization performed by `StandardAnalyzer`, and what analyzers are in general?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski the docs has TotalHits 1, so I assume that it finds the document. I am not aware of the tokenization performed by StandardAnalyzer

Comment: Hmm.. Quite honestly, I don't see why the document you're storing in the index would match your query. The query parser yields a `TermQuery`, which can only match a whole term - in your case, it's roughly equivalent to a whole word. If you don't know what the analyzers do, I suggest you to read about it because it's *very* important to understand. Also, you can use the *Luke* tool to view exactly what's stored in the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can geht the results as follows:

```cs
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("body", "body"));
TopDocs docs =  searcher.Search(query,5);

// Get id and score for the top docs
ScoreDocs[] results = docs.ScoreDocs

foreach (ScoreDoc item in results)
{
    // Get lucene docID
    int luceneID = item.Doc

    // Get actual document for the docID from index
    Document doc = searcher.Doc(luceneID);
}
```

Lucene(.Net) has its own unique docIDs for the indexed documents, which is independent from the ID stored in your ID field. You can access the actual Document and its stored fields by calling `searcher.Doc(int docID)` or for an `IndexReader` you can call `reader.Doc(int docID)`